# SSPI Provider: Server not found in Kerberos database SQL 2017 Linux

Tags: linux, sql-server-2017

Ok, I have followed the steps from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-2017 to try and fix this issue as well as the SUSE/Redhat documentation for connecting to an AD server.

The servers are on the domain, I can log into the servers with my domain credentials but when I attempt to login to SQL as a domain user ( that is a Sysadmin on the SQL Server ) I get a the Login failed, the login is from an Untrusted domain and cannot be used with integrated authentication ( Error 18452) when attempting to use SSMS from a Windows box that works if I log in with a local account from it. When I log in as the domain user on the linux box I get the SSPI Provider: Server not found in Kerberos database and Cannot Generate SSPI context. Iif I use sqlcmd for a local user connecting to the FQDN of either server it connects fine. I haven't touched Linux from an Admin standpoint in over 15 years.

This is on both a SUSE 12 SP2 and a Redhat 7.5 server in our test environment. Not a big deal for me but our users are complaining because they now need a local account to log in for testing purposes instead of just using their domain accounts like the Windows side of things. Any help is greatly appreciated, most of what I am finding online just points me back to the Microsoft document and I have basically rebuilt the servers a couple times trying to add it to the domain before installing SQL and also after installing SQL to see if that made any difference, get the same error both ways.

Comment: With GSSAPI, `Server not found in Kerberos database` would suggest `/etc/krb5.conf` is incomplete, and the Kerberos client does not know which KDC is in charge of service tickets for that target. Or a server name that is not a canonical DNS entry. With SSPI... go figure.

Comment: If that was the issue would kinit still work? I can run kinit, authenticate, and then do a klist and see the service principal and ticket start and end dates.

Comment: `klist` creates the TGT. It cannot guess which service tickets you will need e.g. `http/some.host.fqdn@SOME.REALM` > that's the job of your client lib (whether HTTP or LDAP or SQL Server)

Comment: On Windows, run the `klist` that comes with Windows (not the one that comes with Java !) to see what service tickets look like. The SSPI way.